# $PATH variable for every running process in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, redhat

How I can find `$PATH` variable for every running process on my Linux system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find them in `/proc/*/environ`. This are pseudo-files containing the environment for each process. If you really want to fetch all, you have to do it as root.

The content of the `environ` files are `NUL` separated environment entries.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading and parsing the contents of the /proc/$pid/environ file
You should be able to enumerate over all the PID directories in /proc/ and pull out the PATH variables from there.